# How to get HRTF sound on Linux

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, ffmpeg, music, music-player

I recently switched from macOS to Ubuntu, and there's only one thing I miss: It's the [Boom3D](https://www.globaldelight.com/boom/) application, which allows you to apply effects on music, especially the "Spatial Audio" effect that I like a lot.

After some research, it seems to me that the exact term is [HRTF (Head-related transfer function)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-related_transfer_function), I also heard about [SOFA files](https://www.sofaconventions.org/mediawiki/index.php/SOFA_(Spatially_Oriented_Format_for_Acoustics)).

How to get this on Linux?
Here is a video demonstration of the kind of audio effects I want to get: [HRTF Demo - Steam Audio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6SDKfHCDm8)

Whether it's a music player, an ffmpeg script, or a system-wide solution, I'm interested!

Comment: ffmpeg has the [sofalizer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sofalizer) filter: "SOFAlizer uses head-related transfer functions (HRTFs) to create virtual loudspeakers around the user for binaural listening via headphones"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get a **system-wide solution**!

Several steps:

1. Create a sink

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink \
sink_name=SantaClaus \
sink_properties=device.description=SantaClaus
```

2. Set it as default (can be done using **pavucontrol**)

```
pacmd set-default-sink SantaClaus
```

3. ffmpeg (see [the doc](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#pulse-1) to output to pulseaudio)

```
ffmpeg \
-loglevel error \
-f pulse \
-i SantaClaus.monitor \
-af "sofalizer=sofa=/path/ClubFritz9.sofa" \
-f pulse \
-name "3D Audio" \
"3D Audio"
```

4. Use **pavucontrol** to select the output of ffmpeg (named 3D Audio), choose your headphones or speakers

_

[Here is a problem I encountered](https://superuser.com/q/1651318/775371) specific to version 0.6 of libmysofa